# Groovy 2.4 variable scope in closure with @Field annotation

Tags: groovy

Can someone explain to me why in closure2 `initVars('c')` is not able to modify the referenced object if `@Field` is used in declaration?

```
import groovy.transform.Field;

@Field def lines4 = "a";

void initVars(String pref){
    println('init:'+lines4+'  '+pref)      //*3.init:a  b   *7.init:b  c
    lines4 = pref;  
}
println("closure1")    ///1. closure1
1.times {
    println(lines4)    ///2. a
    initVars('b')      ///3. init:a  b
    lines4 += 'p1'
    println(lines4)    ///4. bp1
}
println("closure2")    ///5. closure2
1.times {
    println(lines4)    ///6. bp1
    initVars('c')      ///7. init:b  c
    println(lines4)    ///8. bp1     Why not c
    lines4 += 'q1'
    println(lines4)    ///9. bp1q1   Why not cq1
}
```

Output:

```
C:\projects\ATT>groovy test.groovy
1. closure1
2. a
3. init:a  b
4. bp1
5. closure2
6. bp1
7. init:b  c
8. bp1
9. bp1q1
```

Output without `@Field` and `def`, with just `lines4 = "a"` in script scope. This appears normal to me.

```
C:\projects\ATT>groovy test.groovy
1. closure1
2. a
3. init:a
4. bp1
5. closure2
6. bp1
7. init:bp1
8. c
9. cq1
```

I saw same behavior in groovy2.5-beta and groovy 2.6-alpha.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using `@Field` annotation on a script variable changes a scope of this variable from a local one to a `Script` class one:

> Variable annotation used for changing the scope of a variable within a script from being within the run method of the script to being at the class level for the script.
>
> The annotated variable will become a private field of the script class. The type of the field will be the same as the type of the variable. Example usage:
>
> ```
> import groovy.transform.Field
> @Field List awe = [1, 2, 3]
> def awesum() { awe.sum() }
> assert awesum() == 6
> ```
>
> In this example, without the annotation, variable awe would be a local script variable (technically speaking it will be a local variable within the run method of the script class). Such a local variable would not be visible inside the awesum method. With the annotation, awe becomes a private List field in the script class and is visible within the awesum method.
>
> *Source: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/gapi/groovy/transform/Field.html*

Every Groovy script extends [`groovy.lang.Script`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html) class and the body of the script is executed inside [`Script.run()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/api/groovy/lang/Script.html#run--) method. Groovy passes variables to this script using [`Binding`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html) object. When you change a scope of a local script variable to a class level then there is no binding for this variable passed to a closure, because `binding` object **contains only local-scoped variables**. Compare these two screenshots I made. First one shows what the `binding` object looks like when we call `initVars(String pref)` for the first time and `lines4` is a local script variable:

[image]

And here is same breakpoint but now `lines4` is a `@Field def lines4` variable:

[image]

As you can see there is no binding for `lines4` variable in `binding` object, but there is a class field called `lines4`, while this binding is present in the first screenshot attached.

When you call

```
lines4 += 'p1'
```

in the first closure, local binding for `lines4` is created and it is initialized with a current value of a `this.lines4` value. It happens because `Script.getProperty(String property)` is implemented in following way:

```
public Object getProperty(String property) {
    try {
        return binding.getVariable(property);
    } catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
        return super.getProperty(property);
    }
}
```

*Source: https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java#L54*

So it firstly checks if there is a binding for a variable you access in the closure and when it does not exist it passes execution to a parent's `getProperty(name)` implementation - in our case it just returns class property value. At this point `this.lines4` is equal to `b` and this is the value that is returned.

`initVars(String pref)` method accesses class field, so when you call it it always overrides `Script.lines4` property. But when you call

```
lines4 += 'q1'
```

in the second closure, the binding `lines4` for a closure already exists and its value is `bp1` - this value was associated in the first closure call. That's why you don't see `c` after calling `initVars('c')`. I hope it helps.

#### UPDATE: How `binding` works in a script explained

Let's get a little deeper to get better understanding what is going on under the hood. This is what your Groovy script looks like when it is compiled to a bytecode:

```
Compiled from "script_with_closures.groovy"
public class script_with_closures extends groovy.lang.Script {
  java.lang.Object lines4;
  public static transient boolean __$stMC;
  public script_with_closures();
  public script_with_closures(groovy.lang.Binding);
  public static void main(java.lang.String...);
  public java.lang.Object run();
  public void initVars(java.lang.String);
  protected groovy.lang.MetaClass $getStaticMetaClass();
}
```

Two things worth mentioning at this moment:

1. `@Field def lines4` is compiled to a class field `java.lang.Object lines4;`
2. `void initVars(String pref)` method is compiled to `public void initVars(java.lang.String);` class method.

For a simplicity you can assume that the rest content (excluding `lines4` and `initVars` method) of your script is inlined to `public java.lang.Objectrun()` method.

`initVars` always accesses class field `lines4` because it has direct access to this field. Decompiling this method to a bytecode shows us this:

```
  public void initVars(java.lang.String);
    Code:
       0: invokestatic  #19                 // Method $getCallSiteArray:()[Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
       3: astore_2
       4: aload_2
       5: ldc           #77                 // int 5
       7: aaload
       8: aload_0
       9: aload_2
      10: ldc           #78                 // int 6
      12: aaload
      13: aload_2
      14: ldc           #79                 // int 7
      16: aaload
      17: aload_2
      18: ldc           #80                 // int 8
      20: aaload
      21: ldc           #82                 // String init:
      23: aload_0
      24: getfield      #23                 // Field lines4:Ljava/lang/Object;
      27: invokeinterface #67,  3           // InterfaceMethod org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.call:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      32: ldc           #84                 // String
      34: invokeinterface #67,  3           // InterfaceMethod org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.call:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      39: aload_1
      40: invokeinterface #67,  3           // InterfaceMethod org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.call:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      45: invokeinterface #52,  3           // InterfaceMethod org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.callCurrent:(Lgroovy/lang/GroovyObject;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
      50: pop
      51: aload_1
      52: astore_3
      53: aload_3
      54: aload_0
      55: swap
      56: putfield      #23                 // Field lines4:Ljava/lang/Object;
      59: aload_3
      60: pop
      61: return
```

Operation 56 is a opcode for a assigning value to a field.

Now let's understand what happens when both closures gets called. First thing worth mentioning - both closures have `delegate` field set to the script object that is being executed. We know that it extends `groovy.lang.Script` class - a class that uses [`binding` private field](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java#L36) to store all bindings (variables) available in the script runtime. This is important observation, because `groovy.lang.Script` class overrides:

- [`public Object getProperty(String property)`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java#L54)
- [`public void setProperty(String property, Object newValue)`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java#L62)

Both methods use `binding` to lookup and store variables used in the script runtime. `getProperty` gets called any time you read local script variable and `setProperty` gets called any time you assign a value to script local variable. That's why code like:

```
lines4 += 'p1'
```

generates sequence like:

```
getProperty -> value + 'p1' -> setProperty
```

In your example first attempt of reading `lines4` ends up with returning a value from parent class (it happens if binding is not found, then [`GroovyObjectSupport.getProperty(name)` is called](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java#L58) and this one returns a value of a class property with given name). When closure assigns a value to a `lines4` variable then a binding is created. And because both closures share same `binding` object (they use delegate to the same instance), when second closure reads or writes `line4` variable then it uses previously created binding. And `initVars` does not modify binding because as I shown you earlier it accesses class field directly.

Comment: So if I get it correct, in case of `@Field def lines4` class variable is not used directly by closures, it creates a binding object and values are copied over to the binding object `binding.lines4`. Until this it seems logical, but that last part if the binding already exists for a previous closure and that being reused is strange.

Comment: @samarjitsamanta No worries, I have updated the answer with more detailed explanation. Hope it helps.