# Jenkins method cannot get variable (groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: variable for class: groovy.lang.Binding)

Tags: jenkins, groovy

Currently I'm trying to make this (simplified) Jenkins pipeline script.
Please help me find out how to pass the string VAR1 correctly. I tried using bared VAR1, {var1}, "{VAR1}", or like below (I know that some seems stupid but I'm kind of desperate) yet nothing worked.

```
def VAR1 = 'build architectures'
def BuildANew(variables)
{
   echo "Build declaration"
   build job: 'LocalJenkins', parameters:[
        extendedChoice(name: 'VAR1', value: ${VAR1}),
        param(name:'Variables', value:variables)
    ]
}

pipeline{
   ...
   stages{
      stage("Build"){
         parallel{
            stage("Build1"){
               agent{
                  label 'label'
               }
               steps{
                  BuildANew(parameters)
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And it returned this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: VAR1 for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:271)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at WorkflowScript.BuildANew(WorkflowScript:39)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:155)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In a Groovy script, scopes can be different from a typical class itself. Hence you need to explicitly change the `scope` of global variables if you are accessing them from other functions.  In order to change the variable scope, you can use `@Field` annotation which changes the scope of the variable from a local to a `Script class` variable.

You have two options here.

**Use @Field annotation to change the scope of the variable**

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def VAR1 = 'build architectures'

def BuildANew(variables)
{
   echo "Build declaration"
   build job: 'LocalJenkins', parameters:[
        extendedChoice(name: 'VAR1', value: ${VAR1}),
        param(name:'Variables', value:variables)
    ]
}

pipeline{
   ...
   stages{
      stage("Build"){
         parallel{
            stage("Build1"){
               agent{
                  label 'label'
               }
               steps{
                  BuildANew(parameters)
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Pass the variable to the function from your pipeline**

```
def VAR1 = 'build architectures'
def BuildANew(variables, VAR1)
{
   echo "Build declaration"
   build job: 'LocalJenkins', parameters:[
        extendedChoice(name: 'VAR1', value: ${VAR1}),
        param(name:'Variables', value:variables)
    ]
}

pipeline{
   ...
   stages{
      stage("Build"){
         parallel{
            stage("Build1"){
               agent{
                  label 'label'
               }
               steps{
                  BuildANew(parameters, VAR1)
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

If you want to read more. There is a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46580819/2627018).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, could be imperfect but it works, for now.

```
VAR1 = 'build architectures'
def BuildANew(variables)
{
   echo "Build declaration"
   build job: 'LocalJenkins', parameters:[
        extendedChoice(name: 'VAR1', value: ${VAR1}),
        param(name:'Variables', value:variables)
    ]
}
```